# Why can't my compiler find my function?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am just learning how to use C/C++ and am trying to write a program in which "otherPerson" (first name, last name) inherits from "person" (first name).  I'm stuck on the compareTo function for person.  It is supposed to sort an array of pointers to person alphabetically by first name.  (not sure if I expressed that idea correctly). The end goal is to print the sorted contents of the array.

I keep getting:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl compareTo(class person * * const,int)" (?compareTo@@YAXQAPAVperson@@H@Z) referenced in function _main
>   1>c:\users\laur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

when I try to build.  I've looked around the internet for more information, but I'm pretty sure my include statements are correct.  The function is intended as a member function.

Test.cpp:

```
#include "stdio.h"
   #include "otherPerson.h"
   #include<iostream>
   #include <string>
   using namespace std;
      void compareTo(person *array[7], int );
       int main(){
           int length = 7;
           person* epicJourney[6];
          //fill array
           compareTo(epicJourney, length);
```

person.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class person {
    protected:
        string firstName;
    public: 
        person(string firstName);
        virtual void setFirstName(string firstName);
        virtual string getFirstName();  
        virtual void compareTo (person *array[7], int length);
        virtual string toString();
};
```

person.cpp:

```
#include "person.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
person::person(string firstName){
    this->firstName = firstName;
}

void person::setFirstName(string aName){
    firstName =aName;
}

string person::getFirstName(){
    return ((*this).firstName);
}

string person::toString(){
    return (this->firstName);
}

void person::compareTo(person *array[], int length){
    int i;
    int j;

    person *current;

    for (i=1; i<length; i++){
        current = array[i];
        for (j=i; j>=1 && (current < array[j-1]); j--){
            array[j] = array[j-1];
            array[j-1] = current;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you compile them? Maybe you do not link the Test.cpp and the person.cpp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions from new programmers are most certainly welcome here, but you need to help us out a bit.  Unfortunately, I had to downvote this question because it contains a giant wall of code, most of which is not relevant to the problem.  If you can reduce your question down to the bare minimum of code that exhibits the problem, I'll change my vote.

Comment: As a bonus, by reducing your problem to its bare essentials, you might find the solution yourself.  Feel free to post the answer here if you do.

Comment: Hmmm, (re-) reading the OPs goal description, I think `person::compareTo()` should be designed to just compare to another instance of person class and `::compareTo()` should be renamed to `::sortPersons()` and receive the actual implementation from `person::compareTo()` (using the new `person::compareTo(const person& rhs)` method for comparison). Just some hints ...

Answer (score 2):

You prototype is `void compareTo(... );` but your actual implementation is `void person::compareTo(...)` .    You have to make up your mind: do you want a class member function?

Comment: I was trying to make it a class member function.  So I'm guessing it doesn't get declared outside of main?  I'm sorry. I'm so confused.

Comment: @LauraH: The member function is correctly declared in your person.h file.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the definition of this standalone function, :

```
void compareTo(person *array[7], int );
```

You need to add the definition in your program somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You define a function `person::compareTo`, which is **different** from the function `compareTo` declared in Test.cpp (because the former is a member function of `person`, while the latter is a global function).

Comment: What's actually missing is the definition of `::compareTo()`.